# How to apply optional validation using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two text box and i am applying jquery validaion rule on that. I have done that and it is working fine but i want optional filed like from two of the box i want atleast on box to be filed. If i leave blank both of them it should give error so how to apply this and what change i required in this code given below

```
<script>
 $.validator.addMethod("box_not_same", function(value, element) {

   return $('#box2').val() == value;
}, "box1 value and box2 value cannot be same..");

    $("#f1").validate({
        rules: {
            box1: "required",

            box2: {
                  required: true,
                   Password_not_same:true     
               }
        },
        messages: {
            box1: "Enter box1 value",   
            box2: {
                    required : "Enter value in box2",
                   box_not_same:"box1 value and box2 value cannot be same.",    
               }

        }

    });  
</script>
<input id="box1" name="box1" value=""/>
<input id="box2" name="box2" value=""/>
```

Comment: What is `Password_not_same`?

Comment: Please fix your spelling and grammar so we can better understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I have two text box and i am applying jquery validaion rule on that. I
>   have done that and it is working fine but i want optional filed like
>   from two of the box i want atleast on box to be filed. If i leave
>   blank both of them it should give error"*

If I understand correctly, you have two text inputs and the user *must* fill in one or the other?

In that case, you can use [the `require_from_group` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/#require-from-group-method) included in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js).

```
rules: {
    box1: {
        require_from_group: [1, "[name^='box']"]
    },
    box2: {
        require_from_group: [1, "[name^='box']"]    
    }
},
```

In your case I used the "starts with" selector to target all elements whose `name` starts with `box`.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3T8Tr/**

This is the documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/#require-from-group-method